# Storing JS variable before react js loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-4

We have Rails app with react as front-end framework .. I need to store some hash value in javascript variable like

```
windows.FeatureFlag = {featureA: true, featureB:false}
```

before all files are loading...
we are loading the js file in the following order

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require react-server
//= require react_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

I'm trying to set the above FeatureFlag before the react js loaded... I have tried adding `DOMContentLoaded`  but still, the variable **defined** as  **undefined**..

I react file we require/set multiple different values and all are depending on this variable to avoid multiple server calls...

how to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Jared's answer would work but it adds another request for the client, doesn't get preprocessed, needs to be included in all the layouts. I would:

Create a new file for the script... call it react_config.js

```
windows.FeatureFlag = {featureA: true, featureB:false}
```

then:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require react_config.js
//= require react-server
//= require react_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

application.js is already included in the

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Put it at the top of the document `<head>`

```
<head>
  <script>
    window.featureFlags = {featureA: true, featureB:false};
  </script>
  <!-- now load everything else -->
</head>
```

Usually, the `<head>` is in `app/views/layouts/application`.

You may also find `content_for` useful.

Comment: Thank you for your the answer but unfortunately, react execute faster than the rails asset pipeline and I have achieved in the same custom react require file